# Android - Cómo proteger datos sensibles guardados en la aplicación

Tags: java, android, seguridad

Quiero saber la forma de guardar un archivo que contiene datos sensibles dentro de una aplicación.

Es decir, guardar las credenciales para consumir un servicio web de manera que no se encuentren a disposición de terceros que decompilen la aplicación y puedan consumir el servicio sin necesidad de pasar por la aplicación.

Answer (score 4):

**En realidad si deseas proteger datos e información que son sensibles, estos no deberían ser guardados en ninguna opción de almacenamiento que ofrece android.**

lo ideal es que puedas consumir un Web Service sin necesidad de guardar credenciales como cuenta y password en tu dispositivo ya que como comentas esta información pudiera ser obtenida para un uso incorrecto y no deseado por el cliente; para este objetivo se tiene [OAuth2](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate).

[OAuth2](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate) es un protocolo abierto y estándar el cual permite autorización de servicios de terceros lo cual se realiza mediante un "token de autenticación" que representa la identidad del usuario como la autorización de la app.

---

Procedimiento para obtener un token de autenticación válido del Administrador de cuentas de Android:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> El uso de OAuth2 es útil para lo siguiente:
>
> - Obtener el permiso del usuario para acceder a un servicio en línea utilizando su cuenta
> - Lograr la autenticación para un servicio en línea en nombre del usuario
> - Control de errores de autenticación

Revisa la documentación oficial y ejemplos:

**[Autenticación en servicios OAuth2](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate)**

Answer (score 1):

Mucho depende de como almacenas la información, pero te propongo algunas opciones:

1. Almacenar las credenciales codificadas en una Base de Datos **SQLite**, los datos en la base deben ir codificados (puedes usar **base64** y el tipo de dato en la base sería **TEXT**).
2. Almacenar las credenciales en un archivo externo (puede ser XML) y de igual manera el contenido del archivo debe ir codificado.

Para codificar **base64** en Java puedes usar:

```
String originalInput = "test input";
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(originalInput.getBytes());
```

Así también para recuperar los datos y decodificar usamos:

```
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
String decodedString = new String(decodedBytes);
```

Espero te sirva, dejo un enlace de referencia para consultas:

[Java Base64 Encoding and Decoding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-base64-encode-and-decode)